Get the contents of a table cell for all selected rows
I have a table of user info. When you click the button, I want to get the email address from each selected row, output into a comma-separated string.
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">John Doe</td>
      <td class="country">Australia</td>
      <td class="email">john@doe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">Jane Smith</td>
      <td class="country">Canada</td>
      <td class="email">jane@smith.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="tableToEmail()">Get Emails</button>

I got it to work with the following code, but I'm a novice with JS so I assume it must be inefficient:
function tableToEmail() {

  var recipients = [];
  $('input.selector:checked').each(function(){
      var email = $(this).closest('tr').find('.email');
      recipients.push(email.text());
  });
  console.log(recipients.join(','));

}

Is there a better way to achieve this, preferably with vanilla JS if jQuery is not needed?
Thank you!

@Rayon creating a variable in loop again and again will consume memory and time. my suggestion is for speed up the process, and mine one is fully redable too.

@Death-is-the-real-truth - Yours is less readable, your point regarding "memory" is not valid, though. The scope of the variable is within the function hence you assign a value to a variable, you consume it, and as soon as the scope of the function is no longer alive, it's no longer in the memory.

@Death-is-the-real-truth I mostly program in Python -- in Python var email = ... wouldn't really affect the performance of the function. Maybe 1e6 difference, but when working against even an $O(n)$ functions, the impact dissipates quickly.

@LBF  one improvement in terms of less traversal:  recipients.push($(this).closest('td').siblings('.email').text());

@Death-is-the-real-truth - How come it is less traversal?

@Rayon  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291760/get-the-contents-of-a-table-cell-for-all-selected-rows/291764

Here is a vanilla version using eventListeners
Note I added a tbody to make the HTML valid


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // page elements are available
  const table = document.querySelector('table tbody'); // change to suit how to access the table
  document.getElementById('tableToEmailButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const emails = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('input.selector:checked')) // get only the checked checkboxes
      .map(chk => chk.closest('tr').querySelector('.email').textContent.trim()); // trim is always a good idea
    console.log(emails. length > 0 ? emails.join(', ') : 'None checked'); 
  });
});
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">John Doe</td>
      <td class="country">Australia</td>
      <td class="email">john@doe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">Jane Smith</td>
      <td class="country">Canada</td>
      <td class="email">jane@smith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>

<button id="tableToEmailButton">Get Emails</button>



Same in jQuery


$(() => { // page elements are available
  const $table = $('table tbody'); // change to suit how to access the table
  $('#tableToEmailButton').on('click', () => {
    const emails = $('input.selector:checked', $table) // get only the checked checkboxes
      .map(function() { // NOTE this is a jQuery map, not an array.map
        return $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').text().trim(); // trim is always a good idea 
      })
      .get(); // now it is an array
    console.log(emails.length > 0 ? emails.join(', ') : 'None checked');
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">John Doe</td>
      <td class="country">Australia</td>
      <td class="email">john@doe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selector"></td>
      <td class="name">Jane Smith</td>
      <td class="country">Canada</td>
      <td class="email">jane@smith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>

<button id="tableToEmailButton">Get Emails</button>




Thanks! Would the vanilla version be faster than the jQuery version? (jQuery is running on the site regardless, but I'm not sure if that matters.)

No noticeable speed difference, especially not when you load jQuery anyway.
